# How to detect when admin user is on the All Posts page?

Tags: posts, pages, admin

Could anyone be kind enough to descrive how to I can detect (in my functions file) when admin an user is on the 'All Posts' page?

I have tried get_post_type() but it returns nothing.

Thanks.

Comment: What is `All posts` page ? A normal WordPress Page create through WP Admin -> Pages ?

Comment: The 'All Posts' page is shown below the 'Posts' page in the main admin sidebar. The URL for it on my setup is http://localhost/wptest/wp-admin/edit.php

Comment: Ok, anwser provided

Answer (score 2):

If you need exactly on `All Posts` page, Not on `All Pages`, nor `All Products` or etc -

```
if 
(
    'edit.php' === $GLOBALS['pagenow']
    && ( 
        isset( $GLOBALS['typenow'] ) 
        && '' == $GLOBALS['typenow'] 
        || 'post' == $GLOBALS['typenow'] 
    )
)
{
    // Do what you like...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, this is what you are looking for:

```
if (
    'edit.php' === $GLOBALS['pagenow']
    && ! isset($_GET['action'])
) {
    // Do what you like...
}
```

Comment: Not quite. I need it to work when the same page is used to show the results from using the 'Search Posts' form on the same page - e.g., http://localhost/wptest/wp-admin/edit.php?s=test&post_status=all&post_type=post&action=-1&m=0&cat=0&paged=1&mode=list&action2=-1

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [get_current_screen()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen):

```
function do_something_on_all_posts_page() {
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if ( $screen['base'] == 'edit' && $screen['post_type'] == 'post' ) {
        /* Your code here */
    }
}
add_action( 'current_screen', 'do_something_on_all_posts_page' );
```

Comment: This answer doesn't check if the user is an admin - do you additionally need that criteria met in the answer, or were you only mentioning admin in reference to the page location (i.e. is_admin())?

Comment: Thanks. This looks like a much nicer solution, but I need to use this code with the 'posts_join', 'posts_where' and 'posts_groupby' hooks. And when I use the get_current_screen() function from those hooks, I get a white screen in the front end.